# i get a null when i click on symfony toolbar

Tags: symfony, profiler

hi i hope someone can help me

i'm working on symfony 3.1 and i want to use symfony profiler but when i click on one panel (db, or time) symfony redirect me on a new page (http://localhost:8000/_profiler/?panel=request) and return null

what should i do ?

there is my configuration in config.yml

```
web_profiler:

# display the web debug toolbar at the bottom of pages with
# a summary of profiler info
toolbar:              true
position:             top

# gives you the opportunity to look at the collected data
# before following the redirect
intercept_redirects: true

# Exclude AJAX requests in the web debug toolbar for specified paths
excluded_ajax_paths:  ^/bundles|^/_wdt
```

Comment: Do you have any Controllers created that query your database? Or maybe you just have a simple "Hello World" application created?

Comment: i have my own query and it work i just want have more information with the symfony toolbar but when i click on her she return me null

Comment: Have you tried using the debug URL: `app_dev.php` ? So you add that to then end of your Symfony's page URL, then on the bottom you'' see the debug toolbar. So in other words, no configuration is required.

Comment: sorry but i have an 404 when i try this... i don't know what i have to do. for information my synfony project is an api so i don't have template or twig vue

Comment: Do you have a file called `src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php`? If so, can you post that code? Click `Edit` on your post and edit it and save. If you don't have that, then maybe I can post a suggestion. Also can you post your query as well?

Comment: sorry but i work in a society a can't post my code here... my api works well i have a path like you with multiple controller folder inside my api calls work i have my response with a status 200 i just want profile my request see how many time she takes .